# How to point urls to certain pages with Web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have never written a Web.config file before and to note I cannot use .htaccess.  What I am trying to do is fairly easy I believe.  I am trying to point a set of URLs to certain pages and/or crossed with setting up vanity URLs.  Below are the examples I need:

www.mysite.com/test - this fails to go to www.mysite.com/test/  the slash on the end makes it work.  So I want it to work without it.

www.mysite.com/test | get it to work

www.mysite.com/test/index.aspx | goes to | www.mysite.com/test

www.mysite.com/test/page2.aspx | goes to | www.mysite.com/page2 (only the page exist - there is no folder - Like a vanity if possible)

Not sure how to write this, but was trying...

```
 <configuration>
  <location path="index.aspx">
     <system.webServer>
         <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="www.mysite.com/test" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
     </system.webServer>
   </location>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking to rewrite the url. I'm not sue I fully understand what you're after, but if should be pretty simple after looking at [a few examples](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/03/27/some-useful-iis-rewrite-rules.aspx). For instance:

/test/index.aspx -> /test/ could be written as:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <!-- /test/index.aspx to /test/ -->
            <rule name="test index" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^test\/index\.aspx$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/test/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If you prefer a `301 Permanent Redirect` change `type="Redirect"` instead of Rewrite.

Likewise for specific pages:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <!-- /test/page1.aspx to /page1 -->
            <rule name="test pages" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^test/(page\d+)\.aspx$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" /> <!-- {r:1} is the "PageN" portion -->
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```